# MarkLogic content pump mlcp document URI issue

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

I am tring to use the marklogic content pump in ML 7.
Downloaded mlcp from site trying to load one xml.

From [Marklogic documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ingestion/content-pump#id_28664):
The following example loads files from the local filesystem directory /space/bill/data:

> mlcp.sh import -host localhost -port 8006 -username user \
>       -password passwd -input_file_path /space/bill/data -mode local

but it gives me the full path on the -input_file_path.

My mlcp invocation:

> ./mlcp.sh import -host localhost -port 18041 -username xxxx -password 'xxxxx' -mode local -streaming -document_type XML -input_file_path file:/home/hugo/workspace/oplage-mapping/data -output_uri_prefix /data/map

According to the documentation this would give me a document uri like

/data/map/filename

I tried a lot of things, finally putting the file that i wanted to load in the root of my OS which got me the desired result...

Looks like mlcp keeps using the default uri as the full path of the document I am trying to insert from the OS...

Question: How can I control the document uri so that it gives me the desired URI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that `output_uri_prefix` needs to be used in conjunction with another option, such as `output_uri_replace`, `aggregate_uri_id`, etc.

I tend to use `output_uri_replace`; in your case, it looks like `-output_uri_replace "^.*/workspace,''"` would give you URIs starting with `/data`.

Comment: ok iĺl accept your answer, what worked is this ./mlcp.sh import -host localhost -port 18041 -username xxxx -password 'xxxx' -mode local -streaming -document_type XML -input_file_path file:/home/hugo/workspace/oplage-mapping/data -output_uri_replace "^.*/data,''" -output_uri_prefix /data/map